# C++0x noise, bloat and portability

Tags: c++, c++11, portability

At first when I saw the upcoming C++0x standard I was delighted, and not that I'm pessimistic, but when thinking of it now I feel somewhat less hopeful.

Mainly because of three reasons:

1. a lot of boost bloat (which must cause hopeless compile times?),
2. the syntax seems lengthy (not as Pythonic as I initially might have hoped), and
3. I'm very interested in portability and other platforms (iPhone, Xbox, Wii, Mac), isn't there are very real risk that the "standard" will take long to get portable enough?

I suppose #3 is less of a risk, lessons learned from templates in the previous decade; however Devil's in the details.

**Edit 2 (trying to be less whimsy):** Would you say it's safe for a company to transition to C++0x in the first effective year of the standard, or will that be associated with great risk?

Comment: Err... what is your question?

Comment: Argumentative and leading "question". Actually not a real question. Do you even use C++?

Comment: Better? Satisfied yet? Huh? Huh? :)

Comment: Oh be nice Brian Neal, it's fun to hack on people that use inferior languages, but don't scare them off!

Comment: There is always a risk associated with adopting a new version of a language (or any technology for that matter) early on. The value/risk ratio of being an early adopter depends on how badly (and legitimately) your organization needs to move into the new stuff (.ie. new things that will make your life substantially easier), so much that the monetary cost associated to the risk (the unknowns on the new thing) become negligible at best (and acceptable at worst).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Edit: do I (and others like me) have to keep a very close eye on build times, unreadable code and lack of portability and do massive prototyping to ensure that it's safe to move on with the new standard?

Yes. But you have to do all these things with the *current* standard as well. I don't see that it is getting any worse with C++0x.

C++ build times have *always* sucked. There's no reason why C++0x should be slower than it is today, though. As always, you only include the headers you need. And each header has not grown noticeably bigger, as far as I can tell.

Of course Concepts was one of the big unknowns here, and it was feared that they would slow down compile-times dramatically. Which was one of the many reasons why they were cut.

C++ easily becomes unreadable if you're not careful. Again, nothing new there. And again, C++0x offers a lot of tools to help minimize this problem. Lambdas aren't quite as concise as in, say, Python or SML, but they're a hell of a lot more readable than the functors we're having to define *today*.

As for portability, C++ is a minefield already. There are no guarantees given for integer type sizes, nor for string encodings. In both cases, C++0x offers the tools to fix this (with Unicode-specific char types, and integers of a guaranteed fixed size)

The upcoming standard nails down a number of issues that currently hinder portability.

So overall, yes, the issues you mention are real. They exist today, and they will exist in C++0x. But as far as I can see, C++0x lessens the impact of these problems. It won't make them worse.

You're right, it'll take a while for compliant standards to become available on all platforms. But I think it'll be a quicker process than it was with C++98.

All the major compiler vendors seem very keen on C++0x support, which wasn't really the case last time around. (probably because back then, it was mostly a matter of adjusting and fixing the pre-standard features they already implemented, so it was easier to claim that your pre-standard compiler was "sort of almost nearly C++98-compliant".

I think on the whole, the C++ community is much more standard-focused and forward-looking than a decade ago. If you want to sell your compiler, you're going to have to take C++0x seriously.

But there's definitely going to be a period of several years from the standard is released until fully (or mostly) compliant compilers are available.

Comment: That's somewhat reasuring, but will this include changes in the old part of the C++ compiler, such as making int a fixed size? If not, you'd conclude that every compiler will have its set of tweakable settings - which might even make it worse ("3rd party lib this and that requires those settings when compiling for C++0x, but these settings for old school on this particular platform").

Comment: No, these are new datatypes. An int will work as it's always done, but you'll also have int64_t and similar types that guarantee a specific size. Likewise, char and wchar_t will work as they always have, but char16_t is guaranteed to use UTF16 encoding and be 16 bits wide. Nothing significant should change in the "old" parts of the language. A few bug fixes here and there, but nothing that should cause problems. They take backwards compatibility pretty seriously.

Answer (score 14):

1. You pay for only what you use. If you don't need a complex template feature, don't #include the headers it's defined in, and you won't have to deal with it.
2. Lambda functions should reduce the verbosity of STL algorithms a good bit; and `auto` variables will help with code like `std::map<foo, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<bar> > >::const_iterator`...
3. Yes, it will take a while. Many of the new features are indeed in boost, and if you want portability that's what you should be using for at least a few years after the standard is implemented. Fortunately there are only two compilers that cover those platforms you mentioned: g++ and Microsoft's C++ compiler. Once they get support, it's just a matter of time before the embedded toolchains get rebuilt with the new versions. Unfortunately, possibly a lot of time...

Comment: Lambda didn't look as slick as I had hoped; to me looked like longer but fewer lines. Perhaps when I get used to it, I might be able to cut some code.

Comment: It's a hell of a lot better than boost::lambda, that's for sure :)

Comment: Hehe, safe to say that no-one will disagree there! :)

Comment: Wii doesn't use either of the compilers you mentioned.

Comment: It does if you're doing homebrew ;)

Answer (score 10):

Like most of C++ you will pay for only what you need. Therefore if you don't want the "boost bloat" of useful tracking pointers, thread libraries etc. then you don't need to pay for the compilation.

I'm very sure that portability will be addressed with the design, especially since a lot is based on existing portable code from projects like boost. Both GCC and Microsoft VC have implementations of much of C++ 0x already as you'll see from their respective current prototype versions.

Comment: Boost is Bloat! Purely. It taints my favorite language.

Comment: @NTDLS Well then we'll have to respectfully disagree. You can pry my boost library from my cold dead hands.

Comment: @SimonSteele not hating on Boost specifically, but the rest of us wait for things like tracking pointers, thread libraries, etc to be Standardised, as they now have :P with all the benefits that entails.

Answer (score 6):

1. C++ is always going to have hopeless compile times, it's whole philosophy is do things once(i.e. do it at compile time) so you don't have to repeat it at runtime and reduce the performance. And as others have said, don't include a library if you don't need it!
2. C++ will never be very pythonic because of it's aim of being backwards compatible. The verboseness comes from being an old language that had many things added on as the language evolved. As some others have said, lambdas and auto variables will greatly reduce the verbosity as well
3. This is a problem with any big changes to a language, but I think it's widely agreed that the changes will make the language a lot easier to use, so it should get adopted quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually consider #3 the biggest risk short term.  AFAIK, the standard is introducing new syntax in a couple of areas (lambdas) and changing the meaning of previous words (auto for instance).  Code using these features can only be portable if the compiler for every platform you deploy to supports them.

Sure this will happen at some point in time.  But adding a new feature to a compiler is no small feat and takes quite a bit of time.  I would be afraid that it will take too long for these features to be supported in the main compilers and hence inhibit the ability of a programmer to be an early adopter and portable.

Comment: This is true, but the standard takes a very long time to settle as well and compiler implementers are generally making their changes during this time. See my comment about GCC and VC support for most of these changes already.

Comment: The problem will be the same as the one we have already lived 10 years ago: different compilers supporting different subsets of the standard with different interpretation of the ambiguous parts.  Portability and evolution are somewhat antinomic.  A possible strategy is to standardize the compiler -- g++, como? -- uniform language support on all the platforms, but it has other costs.

Comment: Aren't they taking better care not to do the same mistake this time over?

Comment: Well thats the main point of having it be a standard - you have to balance competing interests from different parties and produce something that almost everyone can agree on. I think it does help - but it obviously doesn't work 100%. Having a reference implementation might do something, but no one implementation supports all OS's and platforms that people want to develop C++ code for.

Comment: @Jonas, practically, what do you propose?  Implementing all what is new takes time, so implementation provide it piecewize.  Some things are easier in an implementation than in others.  Some things may already exist as extensions (says long long...).  And obviously in g++, what is done first is what is wanted by those able to put the resources to do it.

Comment: I have no proposition, I just want to know if C++0x is worth the trouble for the next couple of years. I have no doubt that the new standard will make it a better language in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I find that C++0x makes code a lot clearer in many cases.

Build times can be greatly shortened when dealing with heavily templated code, due to variadic templates. boost:: uses a really ugly template overloading scheme to sort of implement "variadic templates" in C++98. This causes compile time to blow through the roof. [Link](http://www.generic-programming.org/~dgregor/cpp/variadic-templates.html)

Range-based for-loops are great as well for readability.

Consider the C++98-ish:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end(); ++itr)
   foo(*itr);
```

Can now be written (implemented in G++ 4.6) as:

```
for (auto elem : vec)
   foo(elem);
```

`auto` keyword reduces syntactic noise as well.

Lambdas are great for use with STL algorithms as well, and makes it more readable when you don't have to separately create C style callback functions or even a whole class.

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of standard things is that compilers can take shortcuts. E.g. the boost template circus needed to implement `is_`*X*`<U>` disappears if you can simply hand off to `__compiler__is_`*X*`<U>`. This could easily save 2 orders of magnitude, sometimes 3.

Answer (score 0):

What's the question here? Of course it's going to take years before compilers on esoteric platforms will implement these features. Don't count on being able to use new features until 3, maybe 5 years in the future. 'He who then lives, then worries', as we say in Dutch.

Comment: My main concern is that moving ahead with C++0x will cause big trouble in six months time; due to build times, unreadable code and lack of portability.

Comment: That's still a *concern*, not a question.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out weather or not to act on the concern, which, given the number of platforms and amount of code, would use a lot of R&D.